# Can we have data/custom attribute for buttons in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, attributes, custom-data-attribute

Hello there im basically from web development i have a requirement where i have to send a unique alpha numeric value from one view to another view on click of the button is  their any way around we can set custom attribute or data attribute for buttons in Ios one like in htm5  ?

Comment: Your best option is to call a custom method from the button and handle it there. Other options are messy.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to subclass `UIButton`.

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton
@property (strong) NSString *myCustomData;
@end
@implementation MyButton
@end
```

You could also override the look of the button within this custom class to apply the same button style to all your buttons at once.